# React Frontend integrated with Go API different ports problem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, go, npm

I have made a certain react js front-end, with a Go API running on different ports.
*In Development mode* (npm start) everything going well and works fine by setting the proxy to the GO API in package.json.
However when going to *the Production or Deployment mode* ( npm run build then npm -s build port xxxx ), proxy in package.json is not readable, and calling API through axios does not request data from the proxy.

Even though giving the full link with port directly gives a cross origin problem in react.

**So any idea on how to set the axios in react js to call the go api running on different port when deploying using npm run build?**

Thank you

Comment: you can use browser extension to disable cors in your browser, but if you want to deliver the content to your user, you have to let you backend allow cors

Comment: or if you have control over the server, you can set up a reverse proxy using nginx etc.

Comment: so there  is no way to let it work in production mode by setting a proxy somewhere in react app without modifying server config or browser cors?

Comment: @ArefHammadi The proxy setting is only for development and does nothing in production. In production you must make sure that the paths resolve. This is documented in the cra documentation. See [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/).

Comment: I have tried to set cross origin header in GO api as '*' and call it when react calls the api, but still getting that request not succeeded because cross origin is blocked.

Comment: @stackoverflow lol, anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consume the GO API from ReactJs Page?
Does the GO API serve directly to public or running behind Nginx or Apache?

Maybe you need to ensure from Developer Tools within browser, does the request actually responded with cors issue.
If yes, you need to ensure whether the webserver (Nginx, Apache) does not interfere the cors. Or you just have to set it on your webserver (nginx, apache) config.

Comment: I am using these:
npm install -g serve
serve -s build

so serving directly not with nginx nor apache 
and it keeps saying Cors are blocked even if allowing it in the GO API in the main function.

Comment: did you ensure your GO API accept request pre-flight? such as *OPTIONS* method

Comment: Isn't the preflight used for post requests? I am using axios for a get request from React Js to Go Api.